# How to avoid collapse actions trigger multiple times

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change a text and `show/hidde` an `svg icon` with classes when click on collapse.

Every time I execute the code above the code executes one more time and I don't know why,

**example:**

```
1st time = `alert(show)`
2nd time = `alert(hide), alert(hide)`
3er time = `alert(show), alert(show), alert(show)`
etc...
```

here is my code:

```
$('span[name="serviceCollapse"]').click(function() {
        var target = $(this).attr("data-target");
        var label = $(this).find("label");
        var span = $(this);


        $(target).on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
            label.text("Mostrar más servicios ");
            alert("hide");
            var arrowUp = span.find(".d-inline");
            var arrowDown = span.find(".d-none");

            arrowUp.removeClass("d-inline");
            arrowUp.addClass("d-none");

            arrowDown.removeClass("d-none");
            arrowDown.addClass("d-inline");
        });

        $(target).on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
            label.text("Mostrar menos servicios ");
            alert("show");
            var arrowDown = span.find(".d-inline");
            var arrowUp = span.find(".d-none");

            arrowDown.removeClass("d-inline");
            arrowDown.addClass("d-none");

            arrowUp.addClass("d-inline");
            arrowUp.removeClass("d-none");
        });
    });
```

EDIT:

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="col-12 mt-2">
 <span name="serviceCollapse" data-target="#service1" data-toggle="collapse">
  <label class="text-custom-primary bold-300">Mostrar más servicios </label>
  <span class="d-inline">arrowDownSvgIcon</span>
  <span class="d-none">arrowUpSvgIcon</span>
 </span>

 <div id="service1" class="collapse mt-3">
  collapsable
 </div>         
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

Set the event handler only once. And in the click event of 'serviceCollapse' check for its state to print the alert message.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="col-12 mt-2">
 <span class="collapsed" name="serviceCollapse" data-target="#service1" data-toggle="collapse">
  <label class="text-custom-primary bold-300">Mostrar más servicios </label>
  <span class="d-inline">arrowDownSvgIcon</span>
  <span class="d-none">arrowUpSvgIcon</span>
 </span>

 <div id="service1" class="collapse mt-3">
  collapsable
 </div>         
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
 var target = $('span[name="serviceCollapse"]').attr("data-target");

 $(target).on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
  var label = $(this).find("label");
  var span = $(this);
  label.text("Mostrar más servicios ");
  var arrowUp = span.find(".d-inline");
  var arrowDown = span.find(".d-none");
  arrowUp.removeClass("d-inline");
  arrowUp.addClass("d-none");
  arrowDown.removeClass("d-none");
  arrowDown.addClass("d-inline");
 });

 $(target).on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
  var label = $(this).find("label");
  var span = $(this);
  label.text("Mostrar menos servicios ");
  var arrowDown = span.find(".d-inline");
  var arrowUp = span.find(".d-none");
  arrowDown.removeClass("d-inline");
  arrowDown.addClass("d-none");
  arrowUp.addClass("d-inline");
  arrowUp.removeClass("d-none");
 });

 $('span[name="serviceCollapse"]').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr("class"));
  if ($(this).attr("class") === "collapsed") alert ("show");
  else alert("hide");
 }); 
}); 
 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually as per your code you are adding multiple event handlers instead you just need to add event handlers on listeners once initially and that would be it.
Every time click is happening more handlers are appended on the event listeners that's causing the problem.

Comment: can you provide an example of how to use listeners?